# A question about the expectation value of a projection operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to understand why the following claim from my lecture notes is true:

> Note that $\langle \psi | \hat{P} | \psi \rangle = 1 \iff \hat{P} \geq |\psi \rangle \langle \psi |$

where $| \psi \rangle$ refers to a unit vector in a separable Hilbert space $H$ and $\hat{P}$ is an orthogonal projection operator. I can see the equality but not the inequality (using the Dirac way of multiplying the expression by kets and bra).

I don't understand why is true. I'm new to functional analysis and most of the stuff I know is from its applications physics.

Comment: You only have equality if $P$ projects onto the space spanned by $|\psi\rangle$. If it projects on a bigger space, there is strict inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$,$Q$ are orthogonal projectors, we say that $P\geq Q$ when $PQ = Q$. If $|\psi\rangle$ is a unit vector, you have :
$$\langle \psi|P|\psi\rangle = \|P|\psi\rangle\|^2 \qquad \text{and}\qquad \|P|\psi\rangle\|^2 +\|(\mathbf 1-P)|\psi\rangle\|^2=1$$
and therefore :
\begin{align}
\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle = 1 &\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (\mathbf 1-P)|\psi\rangle = 0 \\
&\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad P|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle \\
&\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad P |\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi| \\
&\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad P\geq |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|
\end{align}